# Liip ImagineBundle symfony2: change output filename after filter

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

how to change the output filename after a thumbnail filter ? I want to have choice of the filename for seo.

Comment: It's still the same name as the original one, but placed under different path. It has to be that way as Imagine need to find the thumbnail file where there's another request for this file. I think you should provide some code to show what's your issue in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,i know what is the problem...i use Sylius and when you upload the picture, it rename the file. So this is not a imagine issue. I need to find the way to keep the original filename with sylius.